# 2 сервера на разных virtualbox на одном компьютере

Tags: apache, nginx, сеть

скажите пожалуйста, могу ли я поставить 2 виртуальных машины с серверами(на одном apache на втором nginx) и иметь к ним доступ по одному ip и 80 порту? Хочу взять готовые настроенные виртуалки и поставить на 1 комп, но незнаю как их разделить, устроило бы например 192.168.0.1/serv1 и 192.168.0.1/serv2 порты менять не хотелось бы.

Comment: Не можете. Отдельная машина — отдельный IP.

Comment: А домены разные? Domain.com/serv1 и Domain.com/serv2?

Comment: Домен преобразуется в IP, так что всё равно не можете.

Comment: А как же mod_proxy в apache?

Comment: mod_proxy в apache не имеет никакого отношения к IP-адресам машин. И да, вы можете использовать mod_proxy, если хотите, почему бы и нет

Comment: А разве нельзя сделать отдельную сеть для виртуалок, а на хост машине выбирать куда отправлять запрос на основе адреса */serv1 */serv2?

Comment: Нельзя, сетевая подсистема ничего не знает про протокол http и никак не может различать serv1 и serv2. Для разбора адреса нужно использовать что-то умеющее в http, например mod_proxy или аналог

Comment: Так я об этом и спрашиваю, я готов поставить на хост машину что-то что будет управлять запросами, но как это сделать?

Comment: Как поставить apache? Думаю, вы легко найдёте это через гугл или яндекс

Comment: Нет, как его настроить чтобы получить желаемое

Comment: обычно для проксирования используют nginx (это его основная задача). но и apache тоже можно: в поисковике введите запрос «apache в качестве прокси».

Answer (score 0):

Можете установить столько виртуалок, сколько позволят ресурсы материнской системы.
Однако, адреса у них должны быть разные - иначе Вы не получите должного взаимодействия между материнской системой и виртуалками, и между самими виртуалками (если возникнет данная задача).
Ваши web-сервера, соответственно будут иметь различные адреса.
Адресация "192.168.0.1/serv1 и 192.168.0.1/serv2" характерна для разных проектов, обслуживаемых одним web-сервером, только точнее так: "192.168.0.1/site_1 и 192.168.0.1/site_2"